# Style adjustments in a reactJS dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, menu

I'm currently building a ReactJS App, and I needed to implement a dropdown menu.
I currently have the menu built, but I need help for two elements :

- The style of the menu
- The position of the menu

### 1 - Style of the menu

The menu looks like that : 
[image]

But when I hoover the menu, there is a gap between the hovering of a link and the link itselfs.
For example :
[image]
Here I hoover 'Rename', but styling come under it...

### 2 - Position of the menu

**Simple question :** How can I choose myself the position of the menu in my page ? 
Neither relative to the parent element nor in a fixed page position ?

Here are my source codes :

**VerticalDots.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./VerticalDots.css";

export default class VerticalDots extends React.Component {
  state = {
    status: false,
    elements: [
      "Rename",
      "Duplicate",
      "Archive",
      "Delete Permanently"
    ]
  }

  buttonClick = (e, curstat) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({ status: curstat });
  };

  displayElements(){
    if(this.state.status){
      return(
        <div className="show-options">
          {this.state.elements.map((value, key) => {
            return (
              <div className="data-row">{value}</div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown-root">
        <div className="text-box">
          <div className="button" onClick={e => this.buttonClick(e, !this.state.status)}>
            <img src={require("../imgs/3dots-vertical.png")} alt="NotFound"/>
          </div>
          {this.displayElements()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**VerticalDots.css**

```
.text-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.button {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.show-options {
  height: 110px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #7A7A7A;
  border-radius: 4px;

  position: relative;
  background: #EBEBEB;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.data-row {
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  /* margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px; */
  color: #25073C;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.data-row:hover {
  background-color: #1464F6;
  color: white;
}

.drop-text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

.column9:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, a hidden `line-height` was linked 3 branches above.
Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1):

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-engelbart-tuz4y

I couldn't recreate your first issue, can you please clarify further on what's happening on your end? It might be that you have other styles included that are causing that issue.

Regarding issue number 2, normal css rules apply to `.show-options` which is a child of `.text-box`. I am not sure how you want to position it, but one suggestion would be to use `flex`, something like:

```css
.text-box {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

Comment: Indeed I went on your codepen and the error is not here... I don't see from where it can happen, what can help you to find the problem ?

Comment: you can look for any css imports in parent components. Also, you can inspect in your dev console to check that the styles for these classes don't have any extra css rules

Comment: I'm doing it ! But it seems that the parent element 'show-options' has not the same size of the childs, andthat the childs aren't contained in the parent....

Comment: did you set `height: auto` on `.text-box` ?